# Append results of arcpy.TableToTable_conversion to same table

Tags: python, arcpy

How can one append the results of arcpy.TableToTable_conversion() to same table when reading from multiple tables?

Thanks.

```
lf = arcpy.ListFiles()
files = 0
for f in lf:
    files +=1
    arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(f, out_path, "usps")
    print f
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Answer (score 0):

What about just using [Append](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000050000000)? Either after each conversion or better, outside the loop, for all tables at once.

Comment: thanks i will give it a try for sure and let you know.